# Ubuntu Bitcoin Core Node Upgrade - Keeps starting v0.16.0

Tags: bitcoind, linux

I have done this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bitcoin-qt
```

But whenever I start `bitcoin-qt` from my console, it starts up 0.16.0. How can I fix this?

Comment: Try `sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: Thanks for the post edit btw, looks a lot better. Sudo apt upgrade didn't help either.